# Nmake build failed

Tags: visual-studio, openssl

[image]

Tried to compile openSSl. Failed at nmake. I was able to enter "Perl Configure VC-WIN64A no-asm" I just can't compile openSSl. Any suggestions or any more information needed? I am using VS command prompt x64 Native tools.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
nmake clean
... A lot of output ...

nmake
```